# How to add your app specific settings in pyramid rest framework?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyramid, pylons

I am new to pyramid.

The Issue is I am not able to figure out how app specific settings (key value pairs) work in pyramid.

This is what I have done after various google searches and other stackoverflow answers:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    if '__file__' in global_config:
        settings.update(
            load_sensitive_settings(global_config['__file__'], global_config))
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_chameleon')
    # config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
    # config.add_route('home', '/')
    config.add_route(
        'tags',
        '/tags', request_method='POST', accept='application/json', )
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()


def load_sensitive_settings(configurationPath, defaultByKey):
    'Load sensitive settings from hidden configuration file'
    # configFolder, configName = os.path.split(configurationPath)
    # sensitivePath = os.path.join(configFolder, '.' + configName)
    sensitivePath = configurationPath
    settings = {}
    configParser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(defaultByKey)
    if not configParser.read(sensitivePath):
        log.warn('Could not open %s' % sensitivePath)
        return settings
    settings.update(configParser.items('custom'))
    return settings
```

I have a file where I try to fetch settings like this:

```
from pyramid.threadlocal import get_current_registry
settings = get_current_registry().settings
value = settings['my_key']
```

But I always get settings object as None.

This is how I am defining my custom settings in development.ini

```
[custom]
my_key = ''
```

This is how I start my server in develpoment

```
pserve development.ini
```

I have read that request.settings can give me settings, But that approach is not feasible for me as my key contains the name of a file which is 1.5GBs and it has to be present in memory all the time. It takes around 5 minutes to load that file in server, hence cannot load the file on demand.

Please advice.

Thanks a lot for all the help in advance.

**Update:**

**Thanks to all the answers provided, I finally made it work.**

This is how my main function looks like:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_chameleon')
    if '__file__' in global_config:
        init_config(global_config['__file__'])
```

And I made a config file, this is how my config file looks like:

```
import ConfigParser

settings = dict()

def init_config(filename):
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(filename)
    settings_dict = config.items('custom')
    settings.update(settings_dict)
```

Now wherever I want settings, I just do:

```
from projectname.config import settings
settings.get('my_key')
```

And I put my app specific settings (development/production.py) like this

```
[custom]
my_key = value
```

Regards

HM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my working solution:

**config.ini**

```
[APP.CONFIG]
url = http://....


[SMTP.CONFIG]
smtp.server = ...
smtp.port = 25
smtp.login = ...
smtp.password = ...
smtp.from = ...


[DB.CONFIG] 
db.database=...
db.host=...
db.port=..
db.user=...
db.password=...
```

**config.py**

```
import configparser


config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config._interpolation = configparser.ExtendedInterpolation()
config.read(encoding='utf-8', filenames=['path to file/config.ini'])

smtp = config['SMTP.CONFIG']
db = config['DB.CONFIG']
mail = config['APP.CONFIG']
```

**And how i use it in APP**

```
from config import db
host = db['db.host']
```

Comment: Thank you.
Creating a python settings file from the settings (*.ini) file provided at run time is the only feasible solution.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is putting your settings to the app **main** section with dot separated names. Example:

```
[app:main]
websauna.site_name = Trees
websauna.site_tag_line = Enjoy
websauna.site_url = http://localhost:6543
websauna.site_author = Trees team
```

Then you can do:

```
my_settings_value = request.registry.settings.get("websauna.site_name", "Default value)
```

WSGI pipeline does not bring you settings from other sections and you need to reparse the INI file with `ConfigParser` if you want to access the other sections (as far as I know).

If you need to load a lot of data during development time just store a filename in settings and load the file when you need to access the data, so that you don't slow the web server startup.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't want to follow request.registry.settings.get approach to access settings as I am storing a file path in settings, which I always want in memory. request.registry.settings.get restricts me to access settings only in a view. Is there any other way? Like in django, I can access settings with from django.conf import settings anywhere, not necessarily in a view, same thing I am looking in pyramid.  I have to load this (GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz)[https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/]

Comment: Because that file is to large, I want to always have it in memory instead of loading it on every request. Any suggestions?

Comment: "request.registry.settings.get restricts me to access settings only in a view" <- this is not true.

Comment: You can also do *config.registry.settings*

Comment: But regarding loading time, you should keep such data in database, not in a file. This is a generic Python question, not specific to Pyramid.

Comment: "request.registry.settings.get restricts me to access settings only in a view" <- this is not true. request is a parameter in a Viewset class method. How will I use request outside views?  Can you elaborate how one can access settings using request outside of view?  I have a class X:    __model = function(filename) ...type class. I want to get filename from settings.

Comment: In `main` you have `Configurator` which has `registry.settings`. Just call any function you need to access settings from `main` with `config` as argument.

Comment: I guess, it will work for me. Thank you :)
I'll mostly use a mixed approach. Will make a separate config file(*.py) and pass the config filename(*.ini whether dev or prod), to a function of the config file passing the filename.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you are using PasteDeploy with Pyramid, [the Pyramid docs here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/paste.html#default-section-of-a-pastedeploy-ini-file) explain how you can use a `[DEFAULT]` section in your `.ini` configuration file to hold your custom parameters.

You might also benefit from reading [the documentation on `.ini` files](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/environment.html#adding-a-custom-setting), since it gives some snippets which make it all much clearer.